# saving listview into SQLite database - unhandled exception

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, listview

I need help saving listview into a SQLite database, using this to implement the libraries.

```
Using Finisar.SQLite;
```

However, evyritme I try to save the database, I get this error while sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is highlighted.

> An unhandled exception of type 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll
>
> Additional information: near "modified": syntax error

**EDIT:**

**I have fixed some issues, however now I am getting similiar error "near "values": syntax error"**

```
private void writeResultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DemoT.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();

    sql_cmd.Connection.Open();

    foreach(ListViewItem item in resultsList.Items)

    {

        sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnHeader1", "value1");

        sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnHeader2", "value2");

        sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnHeader3", "value3");

        sql_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (Path,Size,LastModified) values (@columnHeader1,@columnHeader2,@columnHeader3)";

   sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }



    sql_cmd.Connection.Close();

    sql_cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: You have a space in your column name: "Last modified".

Comment: Thank you, however now Im getting an exception "near "Values": syntax error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you want to modified this a little but this is the gist

```
private void writeResultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DemoT.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [tablename] ( [column1]....";

    sql_cmd.Connection.Open();
    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    foreach(ListViewItem item in resultsList.Items)    
    {    
        sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnHeader1", "value1");    
        sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnHeader2", "value2");    
        sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnHeader3", "value3");

        sql_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO notes (Path,Size,LastModified) values (@columnHeader1,@columnHeader2,@columnHeader3)";

        sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    }   

    sql_cmd.Connection.Close();

    sql_cmd.Dispose();
}
```